# How can i build my app with old ios version on new iOS 7 and Xcode 5

Tags: ios, ipad, ios7

I have updated my mac with ios7 xcode 5... ui is change... can i build my pp with older version. i mean is there any seeting which will allow me to build my app on older version from new one.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK .. The only way to do this will be to download the older SDKS and link them to XCode.

With iOS7 SDK you can still set your deployment target to iOS6 and things like Autolayout etc will work.

Really supporting older versions of the SDK might actually not be worth it since API deprecations etc might cause your app to break in the real world.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution to my problem after doing experiments... hope this is correct as result is what i wanted...

i copied all SDK from my old Xcode 4.6 folder after opening content package folder and then found SDKs inside to my new Xcode5 folder.

then i got option to change base SDk was showing both SDK for new and old ios. selected for 6.1 and also deployment target  to 6.1....and yes i got my UI back ....everything was same that for ios6.1.

hope i will not get any issue when i will upload it on itunes...

Answer (score 0):

- Set your deployment target to 6.0 in your `Xcode5` project.
- Build & Archive your project to create an `.ipa` file.
- Install it in your `iOS7` device using `iTunes`.